Which Tehila is said before Bentching on minor holidays like Yom Yerushalayim or Pesach Sheini?
Most bentchers and siddurim talk about Shabbos, festivals, weddings, bris, pidyon ha-ben. In this context festivals usually mean Yom Tov but do they really mean "any day or occasion where you don't say tachanun"?

I’ve heard from my Rav that any day that tachanun is not said you say Shir HaMaalot. So yes on Yom Yerushalayim you would say it. The entire month of Nissan you would say it, etc

(יא) חורבן בית המקדש – כתב של"ה, שבכל סעודה יאמר "על נהרות בבל"; ובשבת, וכן בימים שאין אומרים בהם תחנון, יאמר "שיר המעלות בשוב ה'" וגו'. והעיקר שיידע מה קאמר, ואחר כוונת הלב הן הדברים.
https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.1.11

The Mishna Berura provides a clear opinion at 1:3:11 (translation from https://torah.org/learning/mishna-berura-s1/ )
MB 11: The destruction of the Temple. — The Shla”h wrote that at every meal [before saying Grace after Meals] one should recite “By the waters of Babylon” [“Al Naharos Bovel” — Psalm 137 — which mentions weeping for the destruction of Jerusalem], and on Shabbat and those days when “Tachanun” [the Penitential Supplication said after the Amidah — see Siman 131] is not said one should recite “A Song of Ascents; when Hashem returns etc” [“Shir HaMa’alos Beshuv Hashem” — Psalm 126 — which mentions the joy at Hashem returning the captives to Zion]. The most important principle is that one should know what he is saying and that his words come sincerely from the heart.
This statement of principle is reflected in the rubric of siddurim with a greater or lesser level of detail. For example, the Koren Siddur states that Shir HaMa'alot is said "on days when Tachanun is omitted."
An example of greater detail is the rubric before Bircat HaMazon of the Siddur Avodat Halev of the Rabbinical Council of America:
"Before Grace After Meals on Weekdays, many have the custom to say ""By the rivers of Babylon" (Psalm 137) in memory of the Temple's destruction. On Shabbat and Festivals, and on such occasions as the meals celebrating a marriage, Brit, or Pidyon HaBen, or a festive meal celebrating Yom HaAtzma'ut or Yom Yerushalayim, it is improper to intrude upon the joy with memories of tragedy. At such times A Song of Ascents (Psalm 126), which describes the joy of redemption is said instead."
So, in principle, on both Yom Yerushalayim and Pesach Sheni Shir HaMa'alot (Psalm 126) is said. That would, however, not be the case for those who say Tachanun on either or both of the days in question.

The quote from Siddur Avodat Halev, by omission, seems to disagree with what you wrote previously about Tachanun. Seemingly they would hold to say Al Naharot on Pesach Sheni even for those modern people who ignore tachanun on it

Indeed the fact that it has to specify "a festive meal celebrating YY" implies the day alone is insufficient.
